# Maple wrong about partial derivative of exponential function?

Tags: maple

When I input this function in Maple:

```
f := (x, y) -> exp(x+xy-2*y)
```

And take the derivative:

```
diff(f(x, y), x);
```

I receive:

```
exp(x + xy - 2 y)
```

But I would have expected it to be:

```
(1+y)exp(x+xy-2y)
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: there is a typo in your code in definition of the function $f$: you have `xy` instead of `x*y`, so Maple thinks (!) that `xy` is another variable rather than the product of two

Comment: I don't use maple, but does it matter that you write $xy$ and not $x*y$

Comment: Ah, silly me! It does indeed work when this is fixed.

Comment: I think that could be an answer, @Ilya. :)

Comment: @AndreasSpörl: for Maple it does. Was one of the reasons to switch to Mathematica for me

Comment: Even in Mathematica **xy** is a variable, not a product.  You have to write **x y** for Mathematica to interpret it as an implicit product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maple understand each (non-predefined) expression of the form `abcde` as one variable. It also works for Mathematica where `abcde` means one variable while `a  b c d e` is understood as a product of $5$ variables. Spaces does not work for Maple formulas typed in plain text, so you have to use `*` each time you want to multiply (works as well for Mathematica).

Comment: Maple does interpret `x y` as multiplication if it is entered as 2D Math input, which is one of the two input forms recognized by its Standard GUI. The implicit multiplication of `x y` is not recognized when entered in (1D, plaintext) Maple Notation.

Comment: @acer: thanks, I didn't know it since never used 2D Math input